# What is the best way to search components

Tags: datasheet

I am a student of Electronic Engineering and right now I am doing my practicing in a company. When I was in the university, I have no problem searching a component, but here in the company needs sometimes normal elements (Level Converters, resistors, capacitance, Reductor DC-DC, etc) but with very good performance, one of my task now is to find a Level Converter with a very high response (at least better of 10ns) and I searched a lot, but I didn't find anything with this characteristic.

However, I think that it has to exist to FPGA or CDML very fast. Maybe the question is very stupid for some people, but there is a better way to find this components that just google it?

I mean, when I was searching that, I putted on Google "Level Converter High response" and searched the most important links and also I was searching in Digikey but I find its Search complicated and I didn't find a better Level Converter that I already have.

How do you search for parts?

Comment: You can search on manufacturer websites:ST, Texas Instruments, Analog, Maxim, etc. That should be a relatively easy to find part. If still you can't find it, post in the forums or open a support ticket with manufacturer. Still can't, search for open hardware designs that might use it and copy parts. IMHO searching in DigiKey, farnell, etc is not a good idea as you good too much crap to filter.

Comment: For example: http://www.ti.com/logic-circuit/voltage-level-translation/overview.html I don't know your application bit I clicked unidirectional and you can easily find this one http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74aup1t34.pdf

Comment: As Andres pointed out, there are a lot of websites you can check components if you were assigned the task to decide which components to use, assuming that no vendor comes up to you and advertises their products. A lot of the time in the business world, vendors will try to get you to use their products for your project. They will provide datasheets for you as well. You can ask them about their products. As someone who works in a large company, NVidia, AMD, and Intel always try to compete and convince us to use their products. The choice is yours ultimately.

Comment: @Andrés thank you for your help! This option doesn't work for the application but with the idea of searching in ST, Texas Instruments, etc was very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KingDuken Thank you I would be present when I need more components speak with the company directly if I didn't find the right one for the application. For now, with the Texas Instruments search of Andres was enough! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I search in this order (usually):

Distributors (Digikey, Mouser, Newark, Arrow, Ect)
It's easier to find information and search multiple sources by using a distributor. Digikey has the best and easiest database to search, then mouser.

If I can't find the part there, or analog parts are easier to search manufacturers, For analog parts I search linear\Analog.com, TI.com, and then other suppliers.

Octopart.com is becoming better all the time at finding parts.

There are some parts that can only be found using a google search, but google isnt' specific enough when it comes to searching parts most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Once you know the part number (whole or partial), shopping by price and availability at [www.eciaauthorized.com](https://www.eciaauthorized.com/en) works well.